# In a non auto-ranging digital multimeter, what do the increasing numbers in the Ohm section represent?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrical-resistance, instrument

For my science fair project I am measuring the resistance of nichrome wires under different conditions. I am using an Innova 3300 digital multimeter to measure the resistance. Other websites have told me to move the pointer to the Ohms section. However, there are multiple numbers in that section. What number should I use and how does changing the number affect the results?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90338/

Comment: Would http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ be a better home for this question?

Comment: This really should be answered in the meter manual.

Answer (score 3):

The numbers on the dial generally represent either

- The largest value that can be read on that setting (from which you deduce the multiplier).

or

- The multiplier.

I believe almost all the digital examples I have seen lately are of the first type.

Comment: If my reading was 0.4 on the 200 ohm setting, does this mean the resistance of that object was 0.4, or do I need to multiply that number by something.

Comment: If it reads "000.4" or "00.4" then it mean 0.4 Ohms. If it reads some other way then you should probably read the documentation.

Comment: @Sam, with a handheld multimeter if you measure 0.4 Ohms, very likely you're measuring the resistance of your test leads rather than the nichrome wire. For such a low value you may need a much more careful measurement setup (or a much longer piece of wire). You might want to ask more questions about this topic on electronics.stackexchange where they're more into the practicalities of things like this, rather than physics where we're more interested in what's ultimately possible or in the theoretical reasons for  things we observe.

Comment: @ThePhoton, 0.4 is just an example based on measuring a key, I have ordered the wires but they have not yet arrived.